# Prove that $\lim_{n\to1}\,-\frac{\zeta'(n)}{\zeta(n)^2}=1$

Tags: limits, riemann-zeta

Prove that:

> $$\lim_{n\to1}-\frac{\zeta'(n)}{\zeta(n)^2}=1$$

I've checked on Mathematica and it's true, but I wanted to know how to derive such a result. L'Hospital didn't help.

Comment: *Hint.* You can write $\zeta(s) = \frac{1}{s-1}+f(s)$ for some entire function $f$. What happens if you plug this into the expression?

Comment: It might be appropriate to add what you know about the Riemann $\zeta$ function in a right neighbourhood of $s=1$. Such identity simply follows from the fact that $\zeta$ has a simple pole with residue $1$ at $s=1$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
$$-\dfrac{\zeta'(z)}{\zeta(z)^2}=\left(\dfrac{1}{\zeta(z)}\right)'$$